# Proper method of moving Docker's data

Tags: docker

So this is mind-boggling that as prevalent as Docker is, that you can spend hours reading and still not have any idea of the official proper method of one of the first config steps - moving the actual Docker data from /var/lib/docker.  I myself have used the good old mv and ln but now see references to that being a no-no which made me read up and ultimately think it warrants one place on S.O. once and for all to duke this out....

Just a couple of the many seemingly official methods widely used today:

IBM says use rbind mounting:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSBS6K_2.1.0/installing/docker_dir.html

This EDU nicely lists another of the most common methods of rsync and ln:

https://opensource.ncsa.illinois.edu/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=114130966

This link nicely lays out taking a totally different approach of attempting to instead alter all the inner workings of Docker itself to point elsewhere:

https://www.rb-associates.co.uk/blog/move-var-lib-docker-to-another-directory/

So, the question is, which (if any) of these three is correct and what are the major pros/cons folks have come across using each?  For example, I see several references to rsync'ing and to avoid moving existing due to Docker's hardlinks and excessive data duplication, but then would that also be an issue in the mount scenario?  You get the idea - what are your experiences.  I'll be trusting the public's upvoting a bit more on this question to determine which is the most widely trusted method in use.